# How I can get input without press enter end without see the input on screen?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I want to create a simple game where an object is moved on the screen with "WASD". The problem is that `getchar` works without press enter but it doesn't take input without show it on screen. How can I solve it?

PS: The program is in C language and on Linux terminal.

```
//my code:
while(1){
    input = getchar();
    if(input == 'a'){/*do something*/}
    if(input == 'd'){/*do something*/}
    //...
}
```

Comment: Read about `ncurses` ([homepage](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), [TLDP (HowTo)](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/)), or maybe [set your terminal to "RAW mode"](https://linux.die.net/man/3/termios)

Comment: there is no general portable way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Linux, you can use `termios.h`, here an emulation of the old `getch` (`conio.h`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static struct termios term, oterm;

static int getch(void)
{
    int c = 0;

    tcgetattr(0, &oterm);
    memcpy(&term, &oterm, sizeof(term));
    term.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
    term.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    term.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &term);
    c = getchar();
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oterm);
    return c;
}

int main(void)
{
    puts("Press Q to exit");
    while (1) {
        int c = getch();

        switch (c)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                puts("A was pressed");
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                puts("D was pressed");
                break;
            /* ...*/
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```